# Moment js problema al dar formato a fechas

Tags: javascript, momentjs

queria saber si alguien a usado moment.js y si de casualidad a tenido problema al usar moment(variable).format('YYYY/MM/DD')

Y el problema es de que tengo dos variables aue hacen utilizacion de dicha linea de codigo lo cual la primer variable si me da el resultado con el formato que necesito, pero la segunda resulta que en ves de mostrar tipo 2020/11/03 me da 2020/03/11

Alguien sabria porque ese resultado?

```
let fecha1 = document.getElementById("fechaInicio").value;
        let fecha2 = document.getElementById("fechafinal").value;

        let fecha1Formateada = moment(fecha1).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        let fecha2Formateada = moment(fecha2).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        console.log(`fecha 1: ${fecha1Formateada}, fecha 2: ${fecha2Formateada}`);
```

y el resultado que me da es fecha 1: 2020/03/11, fecha 2: 2020/03/11;
en este caso me da igual el mal formateo no se porque

Comment: Hola! Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/403659/edit) tu pregunta y añade el código donde estás utilizando esa instrucción y el dato que obtienes de ella.

Comment: ahi esta el codigo que tengo

Comment: en el html selecciono la fecha 03/11/2020 y quiero pasarla a 2020/11/03 cosa que no hace

Comment: Y cómo está definido el campo del que tomas el valor? es un text normal o cómo seleccionas la fecha? Puede ser un lío de configuración regional que asume el navegador...

Comment: es un string como tal solo que se selecciona con un plugin de datepicker

Comment: cosa que igual si lo hago con una fecha tipo 31/10/2020 al intentar formatear da que la fecha es invalida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que las fechas originales son string, debes especificar en que formato estan al usar `moment(fecha, formato)`. En el ejemplo, la primera fecha esta explicitamente en formato "DD/MM/YYYY", la segunda usa "YYYY/MM/DD".

Si no usas el segundo parametro el navegador intentara detectar la fecha usando la configuracion local.

```js
let fecha1 = document.getElementById("fechaInicio").value;
let fecha2 = document.getElementById("fechafinal").value;
console.log(fecha1,fecha2);
let fecha1Formateada = moment(fecha1,"DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY/MM/DD');
let fecha2Formateada = moment(fecha2,"YYYY/MM/DD").format('YYYY/MM/DD');
console.log(`fecha 1: ${fecha1Formateada}, fecha 2: ${fecha2Formateada}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fechaInicio" value="03/11/2020" >
<input type="text" id="fechafinal" value="2020/11/03" >
```

En general, la conversion de formato de una fecha se puede realizar con:

```
fechaFinal = moment(fechaInical,{formatoInicial}).format({formatoFinal});
```

Comment: Ohh entiendo, con eso que me indicaste logre el formato que necesitaba.

Muchas gracias...